# not uploading feature image in WP User Frontebd

Tags: wordpress

I installed the plugin WP UserFrontend. Everything works fine except for uploading thumbnails. By clicking on the button (picture appear below) throws me on the same straitsu with the prefix #. What to do? I've updated the Jquery. I do not know that you can still make

P.s. I used a translator, sorry if something is not clear.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLAI6.jpg